# Groovy private fields

Tags: groovy, private

I read that Groovy, at least in the past, had some bugs (or lack of support) about how private qualifier works. It has been fixed or still groovy does not allow to set private access?

Comment: actually you can set the private access but the groovy default accessor does not care about this privacy. accept it as a feature of java and not as a bug of groovy :)

Comment: Add it as answer so i can accept your indication if you want. Regards and thanks